# Acceptable formats for the jodaDate mapping in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, jodatime, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to use the PlayFramework date mappings and a datetime-local field. [Docs Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms)

A truncated mapping looks like this, with a couple of options I've tried for the validator.

```
mapping(
  "startTimeGt" -> optional(jodaDate),
  "startTimeLt" -> optional(jodaDate("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))
)(...
```

I have tried both the bundled inputDate helper, and a datetime-local field.

But whatever combination I seem to try I get an `error.date` on form submit. I feel like this should be simple, and either I'm missing something in the docs, or they just don't tell me. Has anyone got a working example of the html required and a `jodaDate` mapping?

Comment: I wander if you will post the error log?

Comment: @Jerry There is no error log. I simply get a `formWithErrors` when doing `form.bindFromRequest.fold`. And the error attached to the field is error.date, which translates to the message "Valid date required"

Answer (score 1):

I guess the formWithErrors were caused by the code

```
"startTimeLt" -> optional(jodaDate("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"))// the format maybe wrong
```

because you did not know the format of jodaDate passed from front end to back end. You can print the form content before binding the form from request like this

```
def index() { implicit request =>
    println(request)//it will print the request content and you can find the "startTimeLt" to verify its format
    form.bindFromRequest.fold...
}
```

Good luck

Comment: The format from the form is 03-06-2016T00:00. I have tried using the format string `dd-MM-yyyy'THH:mm` but to no avail.

Comment: @NathanEdwards if you modify your code by discarding the limit of jodaDate format, "startTimeLt" -> optional(jodaDate). Does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried to make that clear in my question by showing a couple of options I had tried.

Answer (score 1):

if the format from the form is: `03-06-2016T00:00`
than you will probably need something like: `dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm`.

P.S.: You should probably use java8 localDateTime, since joda will be seperated in Play 2.6.